# How to calculate specific field for similar datalines in multiple files?

Tags: bash

I have a multiple files with structure

1:

```
57  string1 string2   0   200   0     0    11
50  string6 string7   0   656   676   12   0
```

2:

```
11  string3 string4   2   45    86    0    0
57  string1 string2   0   343   0     0    11
50  string6 string7   0   565   676   12   0
```

I need to calculate sum of all numbers in field number 5 for all rows with the same first field for all data lines in all files.

for example, for lines beginning with 50 it will be the sum of 656+565 = 1221. And for the numbers 57, respectively, 343+200 = 543. After that I want to display a string with a maximum sum amount in the format (for example,for 50): "50 string1 string2 1221".

I may only use these commands: printf, echo, wc, tail, head, grep, sort, uniq, cut, tee, tr, read, with no use of temporary files.

I made a script, but it calculates wrong value: on the file input, it simply calculates the sum of field for all lines in the file, and I need as described above ..
  How to do it (or rather, how to fix it to make it work)? Here is the script:

```
#! /bin/bash

function findMax {

  for file in $* ; do
    cat $file | sort -bd | calcSums 
  done      
} 

function calcSumForSimilar {

  local sum_for_similar=0

  while read -a line ; do
    let sum_for_similar+=${line[4]}      
  done

  echo $sum_for_similar      
}

function calcSums {

  while read -a line; do
    sum=$(cat "${line[@]}"  | grep ${line[0]} | calcSumForSimilar)
  done

  echo ${line[0]} ${line[1]} ${line[2]} $sum
} 

findMax $*
```

Thank you!

Comment: `I may only only use the commands: printf, echo, wc, tail, head, grep, sort, uniq, cut, tee, tr, read, with no use of temporary files. ` sounds like homework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk '{s[$1]+=$5} END{ for (x in s) { print x, s[x]}}' in1 in2
```

Without awk:

```
for k in $(cut -f1 -d' ' in1 in2 | sort | uniq); do 
  s=0; 
  for v in $(grep "^$k" in1 in2 | cut -f10 -d' '); do 
    let s+=$v; 
  done; 
  echo $k $v 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a modern bash, using only builtins:

```
declare -A sum strings

# read all the files
while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 rest; do
  (( sum[f1] += f5 ))
  strings[f1]="$f2 $f3"
done << *

# calculate the max
max=-1
for key in "${!sum[@]}"; do
  if (( max < sum[key] )); then
    max=${sum[key]}
    max_key=$key
  fi
done
```